# I need to remove manually a display from a view

Tags: 7, views

While I was testing an organic groups view it caused a block display in the same view to come up with an error message every time I try to edit it.
I could re-created the block view but can't delete the old block view through the UI.
Is it safe to delete it manually from the views_display table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try, you could also try to delete the display from the 'views_display' table, in any case make sure to do a complete dump of your database so you may restore it if anything goes wrong=)